# Vuejs slice function not reactive

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm using 
- laravel
- blade
-vuejs

For one case i have splice not reactive on array. 
So i have an ul/li (  i have remove css and other stuff )

```
<ul>
        <template v-for="(user, index) in availableUsers"  >
        <li v-bind:data-user="user.id" v-bind:data-index="index" >
            @{{user.fullName}}
            <button id=btnRemove>                            
        </li>
   </template>
</ul>
```

in my vue instance code i have a function removeFromAvailable. 
 i do a call to myvue.availableUsers.slice(index, 1).
the method receive the good index.

```
removeFromAvailable : function(index) {
        console.log(index);
        myVue.availableUsers.slice(index, 1);
}
```

It's still in the list. I'm confused because it's first time it's not working.

Any idea why it's not reactive?

Comment: Can you add more code which will help understand the issue or better if you can create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you need to set the variable again. `slice` just returns a copy of the changed array, it doesn't change the original instance.

```
removeFromAvailable(index) {
  this.availableUsers = this.availableUsers.slice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, after searching a little bit deeper, i found this. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Replacing-an-Array

Comment: Another method would be to use the splice method as it does modify the original array just don't add the third argument.